# Can't change Capslock setting, always resets itself back to "Disabled"

Tags: 10.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

So I disabled Capslock a while ago when I finally upgraded to 10.04  (via *System ➜ Preferences ➜Keyboard ➜ Layout ➜ Options*). Now, I simply want to set it to *Make CapsLock an additional ESC*. But Ubuntu seems to hate Capslock so much, that, as soon as I close the dialog, it resets it to disabled.

My best guess is, that it can't write the setting due to some ownership issues, but I couldn't figure out where the setting is actually stored.

Comment: What you want to do??Do you want to change your capslock to Esc??

Comment: Uh yes? Doesn't the question already state that? If not, them I'm sorry, I disabled it via "Keyboard -> Layout -> Options" but now I can't change the setting for Capslock in that dialog anymore, the settings for all the other keys still works though.

Comment: awesome -- didn't know that there was a method to change this via the GUI.  Something new to test for future alpha/beta releases....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting is stored in `/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/options` in the [[image]GConf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gconf) configuration database.

Make sure that key is set correctly:

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gconf-editor` in the dialog window and click **Run**,

  [image]
- Navigate to `/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/options`,

  [image]
- Make sure there is the item `caps:escape` *(as shown in the previous screenshot)*
  and **not** `caps:none`.

Comment: Thx, that did the job (way less reaching for ESC in VIM now). I tried it via the GUI afterwards again, but it seems that this thing is bugged it **always** sets it to `none` not matter what is in gconf. Anyways I'm fine with setting it via gconf directly :)

Comment: @Ivo Try setting it correctly in GConf and then setting it correctly via the GUI and then close the GUI. That might make it stay "in sync".